# org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException - what does hibernate consider to be the Identifier

Tags: hibernate

With this error *org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session* - what does hibernate consider being the identifier?  Is it a unique value that hibernate assigns to the object OR is it the primary key on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate stores your `@Entity` in its context based on its primary `@Id`, which should usually match the `Primary Key` of your table.

You are trying to save or persist a **new Entity** which is already present in your hibernate Context (from somewhere else in your early code).